# componentsSeparatedByString returns a AnyObject, not a String

Tags: swift

As it's written in the Quick Help from Xcode

> func componentsSeparatedByString(separator: String!) -> AnyObject[]!

So, `componentsSeparatedByString` returns a `AnyObject` type.

After this part of code

```
 let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
    let path = bundle.pathForResource("data", ofType: "txt")
                              /*data.txt is like that :
                     "Cat"
                     "Dog"
                     "Mouse"
*/
    let dico = NSString(contentsOfFile: path).componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
```

Xcode doesn't want me to compare, for instance, `dico[3]` to `myString`.

```
if  myString == dico[3] { //Error : Type 'AnyObject' cannot be implicitly downcast to 'NSString'
       return true
}
```

However, `println("\(dico[1])")` displays a String.

What can I do to be able to have an array full of `String`s (and not `AnyObject` values), thus I'm able to compare `myString` to `dico[3]`?

Comment: It doesn't return `AnyObject`, it returns `[AnyObject]` (`NSArray`).  This is documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution that looks better to me :

```
let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
let _path = bundle.pathForResource("data", ofType: "txt")
var error: NSError?
let dico = NSString(contentsOfFile: _path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding,error:&error).componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
let dicoString = dico as [String]
```

The last line is a downcast of `dico`. Thanks to it, the following line does now work and doesn't display any error.

```
if  myString == dicoString[3] {
   return true
}
```

Comment: I can only recommend doing this if you actually intend to use every index of the `dicoString` array.  Otherwise, `let dicoString = dico as [String]` is extraordinarily inefficient compared to `if myString == dico[3] as? String` as recommended in Grimxn's answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can cast the array like this:

```
let dico = NSString(contentsOfFile: path).componentsSeparatedByString("\n") as [String]
```

Comment: It doesn't work : "Could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments

Comment: @Piercy it fully compiles for me, which part is not working for you?

Comment: Ther's a red dot at the beginning of the "let dico" line.

Comment: weird, I managed to see that too,  "Could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments" - but then it went away and I can't reproduce  :)  @Piercy try to clean (Shift+CMD+K) and see if that helps? or close and re-open the project - Jack's answer should take care of it for you!

Comment: I think I'm doomed, so. :)

Comment: I tried both Shift+cmd+K and closing/reopening Project, but the message is still here.

Comment: Finally it worked after I closed/reopened and added "as string" in the if loop.

Answer (score 3):

Jack's answer is correct, but for completeness, you could also just have changed your test to :

```
if myString == dico[3] as? String {
    return true
}
```

Comment: Finally it worked after I closed/reopened the project and added "as string" in the if loop.